# Manga/Manhwa/Manhua with double-side MC + school

Tags: story-identification, manga

**This is comic I read a long time ago and I don't remember many details. Here are what I remember:**

1. MC has second side which is stronger and can be switched with some kind of mental sea (Like a dream where both sides are in water, without clothes) and this second side has cross symbols (I think on forehead and possibly also on stomach/back)
2. In one scene MC was knocked out (or killed) and then he got up (revived) and made a power punch resulting a strong wind. I think in this scene there was few people watching him.

I don't remember much more but I think action happened mainly at school. And I think it was Korean comic (Manhwa) since it was colored comic (Japanese Mangas are not colored) and usually Chinese comics use either ***Cultivation*** or some kind of ***System***s.

Comment: What do you mean by "second side"? Another personality?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @LogicDictates I don't remember exactly, but I think it was like 2 souls sharing 1 body. As I said I don't remember many details and I am searching it for a long time